# JS - Promise + geolocation.watchPosition

Tags: javascript, geolocation, promise

I'm trying to use JavaScript Promise with geolocation, but can't get to make it work correctly with *geolocation.watchPosition*, the *then* clause being called only once :

```
function Geolocation() {
  this._options = {
    enableHighAccuracy: true, 
    maximumAge        : 10000, 
    timeout           : 7000
  }
}

Geolocation.prototype = {
  get watchID() { return this._watchID; },
  set watchID(watchID) { this._watchID = watchID; },
  get options() { return this._options; },
  // hasCapability: function() { return "geolocation" in navigator; },
  _promise: function(promise) {
    var geolocation = this;
    if (promise == "getPosition")
      return new Promise(function(ok, err) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
          ok.bind(geolocation), err.bind(geolocation),
          geolocation.options
        );
      });
    else if (promise == "watchPosition")
      return new Promise(function(ok, err) {
        geolocation.watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
          ok.bind(geolocation), err.bind(geolocation),
          geolocation.options
        );
      });
  },
  getPosition: function() { return this._promise('getPosition'); },
  watchPosition: function() {
    this.clearWatch();
    return this._promise('watchPosition');
  },
  clearWatch: function() {
    if (!this.watchID) return;
    navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(this.watchID);
    this.watchID = null;
  }
};

var geolocation = new Geolocation();
geolocation.watchPosition()
  .then(
    function(position) {
      console.log("latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + " - longitude: " + position.coords.longitude)
    },
    function(error) {
      console.log("error: " + error);
    }
  )
```

I tried with an intermediary promise returned from *watchPosition/0*, but it returns the same result.

What am I missing ?

Comment: Promises are an abstraction over a _one time_ activity or event. They resolve _once_ and _only once_. Consider using an event emitter instead, or having watchPosition accept a callback.

Comment: Thanks for the precision.

Actually, I was thinking of not using an events emitter or callbacks but promise, because it doesn't require the Geolocation object to know any reference to any other part of the code.

To do so, my goal was to be able to use promise chaining and to call the following code from anywhere : `geolocation.watchPosition().then(okFun).then(null, errorFun)`.

Is there a way to use such a pattern with geolocation.watchPosition ?

Even with a callback passed as a _geolocation.watchPosition_ success response parameter I can't find how to use `geolocation.watchPosition().then`.

Comment: Yes, you're looking FRP (functional reactive programming), check out BaconJS for example. Promises are simply not the correct abstraction for what you're trying to do.

Comment: Alright then. Thanks for all the explanations, I've learned something today with FRP. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Answering to myself.

Following [@Benjamin Gruenbaum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23942339/js-promise-geolocation-watchposition#comment36881676_23942339) advice on using a callback, it's possible to combine a single callback handling both `geolocation.watchPosition` responses with a Promise, and then to use the `then().catch()` pattern (below in the `notify` function) :

```
function Geolocation() {
  this._options = {
    enableHighAccuracy: true, 
    maximumAge        : 10000,
    timeout           : 7000
  }
};

Geolocation.prototype = {
  get watchID() { return this._watchID; },
  set watchID(watchID) { this._watchID = watchID; },
  get options() { return this._options; },
  // hasCapability: function() { return "geolocation" in navigator; },
  _promise: function(promise, cb) {
    var geolocation = this;
    return new Promise(function(ok, err) {
      if (promise == "getPosition")
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(cb, cb,
          geolocation.options
        );
      else if (promise == "watchPosition")
        geolocation.watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
          cb, cb, geolocation.options
        );
    });
  },
  getPosition: function(cb) { return this._promise("getPosition", cb); },
  watchPosition: function(cb) {
    this.clearWatch();
    return this._promise("watchPosition", cb);
  },
  clearWatch: function() {
    if (!this.watchID) return;
    navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(this.watchID);
    this.watchID = null;
  }
};

/* Testing functions from another module */
function log(Data) { console.log(Date() + " " + Data); };
function logOk({coords: {latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude}}) {
  log("latitude: " + latitude + " - longitude: " + longitude);
};
function logError({code: code, message: message}) {
  log("error geo " + code + " - " + message);
};

/* Callback from another module */
function notify(event) {
  return new Promise(
      function(ok, err) { event.coords ? ok(event) : err(event); }
    ).then(logOk).catch(logError);
};

/**/
var geolocation = new Geolocation();
// geolocation.getPosition(notify);
geolocation.watchPosition(notify);
```

Not sure if I use Promise correctly, but it works and allows to take advantage of chaining.

Answer (score 1):

I found this amazing post by **Zach Leatherman**

---

```
function getCurrentPositionDeferred(options) {
  var deferred = $.Deferred();
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(deferred.resolve, deferred.reject, options);
  return deferred.promise();
};
```

**This allows us to do things like:**

```
getCurrentPositionDeferred({
  enableHighAccuracy: true
}).done(function() {
  // success
}).fail(function() {
  // failure
}).always(function() {
  // executes no matter what happens.
  // I've used this to hide loading messages.
});
// You can add an arbitrary number of
// callbacks using done, fail, or always.
```

**To coordinate between multiple Deferred objects, use $.when:**

```
$.when(getCurrentPositionDeferred(), $.ajax("/someUrl")).done(function() {
  // both the ajax call and the geolocation call have finished successfully.
});
```

Source: http://www.zachleat.com/web/deferred-geolocation/